# How to calculate the difference between rows and divide the difference with the value from the previous row in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, diff, transformation

Let's say I have the following dataframe:

```
    A    B    C
1  15   14   12
2   7    1    6
3   8   22    5
4  11    5    1
5   4   12    4
```

I want to calculate the difference between the rows and then divide the difference by the value of the previous row. This is done for each variable.

The result would be something like this:

```
    A    B    C     A_r     B_r      C_r
1  15   14   12      NA      NA       NA
2   7    1    6   -0.53   -0.93    -0.50
3   8   22    5    0.14      21    -0.16
4  11    5    1     ...     ...      ...
5   4   12    4     ...     ...      ...
```

The general formula would be:

R(n) = [S(n) - S(n-1)] / S(n-1)

Where R represents the newly calculated variable and S represents the current variable the value R is being calculated for (A, B, C in this example).

I know I can use the `diff` function to calculate the difference but I don't know how I'd divide that difference by the values of previous rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `across` with `lag` - loop `across` all the columns (`everything()`), apply the formula, and create new columns by modifying the `.names` - i.e. adding suffix `_r` with the corresponding column names (`{.col}`)

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df1 %>%
   mutate(across(everything(),  ~ (. - lag(.))/lag(.),
   .names = "{.col}_r"))
```

-output

```
df1
   A  B  C        A_r        B_r        C_r
1 15 14 12         NA         NA         NA
2  7  1  6 -0.5333333 -0.9285714 -0.5000000
3  8 22  5  0.1428571 21.0000000 -0.1666667
4 11  5  1  0.3750000 -0.7727273 -0.8000000
5  4 12  4 -0.6363636  1.4000000  3.0000000
```

---

Or use `base R` with `diff`

```
df1[paste0(names(df1), "_r")] <- rbind(NA, 
       diff(as.matrix(df1)))/rbind(NA, df1[-nrow(df1),])
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick response! So if I understood correctly, the `~ (. - lag(.))/lag(.)` means apply this formula to all rows (~), where each row is represented as a dot (.) and lag represents the previous row?

Comment: @akrun. How we could apply `across2` here: For the first step: `df %>% 
  mutate(across2(everything(), -last_col(),  `-`))` gives error.

Comment: @Jamess11 `across` loops over the columns, the `~` is a compact way of specifying the lambda function i.e. `function(x) ..`..  The `lag` gives the lag of the column i.e. `v1 <- 1:5; lag(v1)`

Comment: @TarJae Your syntax is kind of looping over two blocks of datasets i.e. one with all the columns and second without the last column .. 1. it also creates an imbalance in length), 2. In addition, the OP I assume asked for difference between adjacent elements within the column instead of between adjacent columns

Comment: Oh I checked it now. I thought OP wanted difference between columns ergo B-A, C-B, It is about the difference of rows. Thanks master.

Comment: @TarJae Also, as the formula is applied within the column, `across2` may not be a good option (or else you may have to transpose the dataset)